# Scaladoc link to another method

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I have two methods on my companion object (model.Product):

```
def apply(p:ProductSyntax)(rs: WrappedResultSet): Product
def apply(p: ResultName[Product])(rs: WrappedResultSet): Product
```

The first method delegates to the second and I would like to indicate this in the docs. I tried using:

```
/**
 * delegates to [[apply]]
 * /
```

But scaladoc complains that this is ambiguous but tells me that

```
(p: scalikejdbc.ResultName[model.Product])(rs: scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet): model.Product in object Product
```

is an option

However I can't work out how to tell scaladoc to use this method. I tried

```
/**
 * Delegates to [[apply(scalikejdbc.ResultName[model.Product])(scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet):model.Product]]
 * /
```

But it tells me that no member is found:

```
Could not find any member to link for "apply(scalikejdbc.ResultName[model.Product])(scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet):model.Product".
```

How would I add a link to the `def apply(p: ResultName[Product])(rs: WrappedResultSet): Product` method?

Comment: try to escape the dots: `[[apply(p:scalikejdbc\.ResultName[model\.Product])(rs:scalikejdbc\.WrappedResultSet):model\.Product$]]`. In general everything that is not a member of your object needs to fully qualified and you need a $ at the end to mark the end of the signature.

Comment: Sadly I get the same error: Could not find any member to link for "apply(p:scalikejdbc\.ResultName[model\.Product])(rs:scalikejdbc\.WrappedResul‌​tSet):model\.Product$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is what I discovered:

1. Everything must be fully qualified, even the class/object itself
2. Package dots should be escaped with \
3. You cannot use any spaces in the signature
4. Paramaters should include the name not just the type i.e. foo(a:String) not foo(String)
5. The signature should end with a *

Finally this worked:

```
[[apply(p:scalikejdbc\.ResultName[model\.Product])(rs:scalikejdbc\.WrappedResultSet):model\.Product*]]
```

HOWEVER ... the backslash escaping and * also appears in the generated html!

[image: Generated html for the scaladoc]

Comment: ah, I suspected you need to add the object. However, you can beautify the link by specifying a label after the signature separated by a space like: `[[apply(p:scalikejdbc\.ResultName[model\.Product])(rs:scalikejdbc\.WrappedResultSet):model\.Product* apply(ResultName[Product]):Product]]`. Though, you may have to escape stuff there, too.

Comment: I'd like to express my utter disappointment with Scaladoc.  This sort of thing eschews good documentation.

Comment: not even these rules worked when trying to link to another class like `[[amf\.client\.remod\.AMFResult*]]`